# MinimumOSVersion is not acceptable

Tags: swift, minimumosversion

I have updated xcode to version 6.3 and converted my swift code to version 1.2.

I'm ready to publish an update on AppStore but it give me an error when uploading my archive:

ERROR ITMS-90068: "This bundle is invalid. The value provided for the key MinimumOSVersion '8.3' is not acceptable."

The problem is that I have no other SDK version available on xcode. In my build settings tab only iOS 8.3 is available.

Any idea?

Comment: have you changed the Deployment Target in general tab to iOS 8?

Comment: Yes, I had to change to Deployment Target of the General tab from 8.3 to 8.0, Thanks you!

Comment: Can I add my answer and mark it as solved Please? :)

Answer (score 1):

As Mustafa Ibrahim said, it was necessary to change the Deployment Target from the General Tab from 8.3 to 8.0, and it works!