# ERROR ITMS-90068: "This bundle is invalid .. minimum OS version 8.3

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I try to submit a binary from Xcode. Yesterday I updated my Xcode to Version 6.3. And I get now this error. Any idea? Change Based SDK?

[image]

Comment: found here some hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641118/minimumosversion-is-not-acceptable  change the Deployment Target from the General Tab from 8.3 to 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same problem yesterday. Setting the deployment target to iOS 8.2 (as I had it before) is acceptable for iTunes - apparently Apple does (yet) not want us to target 8.3 exclusively.